# how to launch supported application automatically from main application

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a main application main1 and two different provider appliation provider1, provider2.

The mainapp will get the data from the provider1,2 apps via contentresolver.

So i have to launch this provider1,2 apps and then i will launch mainapp to populate the data.

is there any way to triger the launching of provider1,2 apps automatically when we launch the mainapp.like via adding the apk's of the provider1,2 in main application.

please share the details.

Comment: yes all are android apps..

Comment: is this provider1,2 apps having  an activity?

Comment: this provider apps are just contentprovider applications, not having any activkities.